# How to subtract dates in the following type using php

Tags: php, date, subtraction

Let's suppose I have a date in this format

```
YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond
```

so for example

```
20130529051043
```

and I need to subtract one second from it until it reaches -3 hours
so until it becomes

```
20130529021043
```

How can I do that using PHP?

Comment: parse it with DateTime::createFromFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$current = \DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis", "20130529051043");
$end = \DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis", "20130529051043")->modify("-3 hours");

while ($current > $end) {
    $current = $current->modify("-1 second");
    // do your stuff
}
```

Procedural version:

```
$current = date_create_from_format("YmdHis", "20130529051043");
$end = date_modify(date_create_from_format("YmdHis", "20130529051043"), "-3 hours");

while ($current > $end) {
    $current = date_modify($current, "-1 second");
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you modify that to Procedural instead of OOP?

Comment: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: In which line do you get this?

Comment: Both lines in variables $current and $end

Comment: `$current = date_create_from_format("YmdHis", "20130529051043");` works perfectly for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30842/discussion-between-user2176428-and-maerlyn)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use strtotime.

```
$timestamp = strtotime("20130529051043");
```

and if you are after the time three hours prior you can just subtract (60*60*3)

```
$three_hours_ago = $timestamp - (60*60*3);
```

and to display use the `date` function

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $three_hours_ago), " is three hours before ", date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class with the method [sub()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)